# Finding the shortest string in a string of words in python

Tags: python, string, shortest

I want to write a function that would return the length of the shortest string in a string of words.
Sample: "I eat apples" would return 1 since "I" is the shorted string.
This is what I did but mincount does neither increment nor set up to 0 at the end of each string. What is wrong with it?

```
def find_short(s):
    min=99
    for i in s:
        mincount = 0
        for j in i:
            print(j)
            mincount += 1
            print(mincount)
        if (mincount < min):
            min = mincount
    return min
```

Comment: Did you forget to indent your code? Also `min` is a predefined function.

Comment: Your first for loop is iterating on a string from what I understand. Hence `i` is just one character iterated over the whole string. The second for loop doesn't do anything since you are asking to iterate over a single character. Your code should work if your first loop was: `for i in s.plit(' '):`

Comment: Is the input for `find_short` a string or a list of words?

Answer (score 4):

```
line = "I eat apples"
mins = min(len(word) for word in line.split())
print(mins)
```

`line.split()` will split line into list of words and then just finding the minimum length

Comment: How about an explanation for the OP of what is going on here. That will make your answer much more useful and more suitable for SO.

Comment: yeah, added description

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest @pramod's answer if you want a quick and easy solution, but I will use your function and show you what happened.

```
def find_shortest(string):
    smallest_length = 99
    for word in string.split():
        current_length = 0
        for letter in word:
            current_length += 1
        if current_length < smallest_length:
            smallest_length = min_length
    return smallest_length
```

#### Changes

- I renamed most of the variables to make their purpose clearer

  - Notably the variable `min` was renamed. Since [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=min#min) is already defined as a function, this may cause issues.
- Changed `for word in string` to `for word in string.split()`. By default [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=.split#str.split) separates the string into a list based on whitespace. Previously you were simply iterating through every character, which is problematic.

Note: `smallest_length` being set to 99 assumes that the length of the smallest word is 99 characters or less. Set it higher for larger words.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` with a key function:

```
# split the string by spaces and pick the min based on the lenght of splitted string
# Example:

string = "I eat apples"
final = min(string.split(), key = lambda x: len(x))

print(final)
# >>> I
```

Answer (score 1):

**A function to estabilish the lenght of the smallest word in a text**

```
def lenmin(text):
    return len(min(text.split()))

lenmin("I eat apples")
```

This will return 1

***Using lambda***

```
>>> lenmin = lambda t: len(min(t.split()))
>>> lenmin("you eat apples")
2
```

Comment: I think you forgot to split the text in your lambda function. the lambda function is returning the length of the minimum character in the string and will be always one. `lenmin('No single character words.')` will return 1...